# Collect flow only when Tab is visible android

Tags: android-fragments, android-lifecycle, kotlin-flow

When we have a TabLayout, each Fragment is going between onResume and onPause when it is visible and invisible accordingly. If we swipe more than 2-3 fragments away, then onDestroy is called. However, i want to collect a flow ONLY when the fragment is visible. I try to use `repeatOnLifecycle`, but there no state that ensures me that fragment is between onResume and onPause. Any idea of how can i do that?

Comment: I'd probably opt for making the collecting flow robust enough to handle callbacks until onDestroy is called. That would be optimal since you would not need to keep track of whether or not the fragment is at the top of the backstack. Could you explain why you do not want to collect values whenever the fragment is not at the top of the backstack?